# Python + Pygame + PygButton detecting

Tags: class, loops, pygame, python-3.3

I'm using Python 3.3 with Pygame and PygButton (low rep don't allow me more than two links)
My files at the moment are [**int.py** http://pastebin.com/sDRhieCG ]  and [**scene.py** http://pastebin.com/Y2Mgsgmr ].

**The idea is** making a mainloop in int.py the smaller as possible. The code has a commented-out example of the start_screen buttons at the mainloop. It works, but with every new screen the mainloop would be bloated.

So I created a Scene class to apply background, texts and buttons. It works, but I can make the buttons work. E.g. the bquit button doesn't quit the screen (as it did previously when inserted into the mainloop).

I'm trying to create a scene_loop() inside the Scene() to run everything the specific scene has to offer. With a button click it would change scene and such, start a new scene_loop.

I can't seem to add specific methods after the Scene class is instanced, so I created a Scene_Start class to deal with specific methods like the scene_loop and its buttons (since the background is easily placed through the Scene class).

I'm just stuck and can't see a way to resolve this without scrapping everything and starting again.

Help?

**tl;dr:**
1. PygButton isn't working outside mainloop
2. How can I create a scene_loop that replaces the mainloop for that scene, "unbloating" mainloop (it would only take care of starting the app and changing scenes).

Thank You.

Comment: Why didn't you paste the code here?

Comment: you don't have any code that quits pygame in the scene.py

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Answering my own question so it can be helpful to others.
Each class have a sceneloop method that runs and "replace" the mainloop. This allows for unbloating and isolating any problem into the scene without affecting the other components.

The mainloop:

```
while True:
    for event in pg.event.get():   
        if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
            pg.quit()
            sys.exit()
    scene.startscreen.draw()
    scene.startscreen.sceneloop()
    pg.display.update()
```

A sceneloop example. This is a method inside the Scene_Start(Scene) class, instanced as startscreen as show above in the main loop.

```
def sceneloop(self):
    while self.scene_loop == True:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if 'click' in self.bcreate.handleEvent(event): #CREATE
                startcreate.draw()
                startcreate.sceneloop()
            if 'click' in self.bstart.handleEvent(event): #START
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if 'click' in self.bload.handleEvent(event): #LOAD
                startload.draw()
                startload.sceneloop()
            if 'click' in self.boptions.handleEvent(event): #OPTIONS
                startoptions.draw()
                startoptions.sceneloop()
            if 'click' in self.bquit.handleEvent(event): #QUIT
                pg.quit()
                sys.exit()
        self.update()
```