# Pygame- "Pygbuttons"- How to change button color and sound play simultaneously

Tags: python, pygame

I want to change the color of each button inside one by one, on every change in color I want to play one sound.

The sounds are playing perfectly, but the button color is changing only at the end when all of the sounds are played.

What should I do the make the color change and sound play for each button at the same time?

Here is my code:

```
import pygame, pygbutton, sys
from pygame.locals import *
import time
import threading
from threading import Thread
FPS = 30
WINDOWWIDTH = 1550
WINDOWHEIGHT = 1200

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
GREY = (211, 211, 211)
exitcode = 0

def main():

    #1 constants
    windowBgColor = WHITE
    size=(100,30)
    running = 1 
    #2 initialize   
    FPSCLOCK = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.mixer.init(frequency=22050,size=-16,channels=13)

    #3 load    
    zebrasound = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/zebra.wav")   
    zlet = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/Z.wav")
    elet = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/E.wav")
    blet = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/B.wav")
    rlet = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/R.wav")
    alet = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/A.wav")
    wrong = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/fail.wav")
    right = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/chime.wav")
    beep  = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/sensor.wav")
    flip  = pygame.mixer.Sound("resources/audio/flip.wav")
    zebrasound.set_volume(3)   
    zlet.set_volume(3)   
    elet.set_volume(3)    
    blet.set_volume(3)    
    rlet.set_volume(3)    
    alet.set_volume(3)    
    wrong.set_volume(3)    
    right.set_volume(5)

    #4 Display
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((WINDOWWIDTH, WINDOWHEIGHT))
    pygame.display.set_caption('Animal game')

    #5 Buttons 
    buttonForward  =  pygbutton.PygButton((700, 900, 600,482),   normal='resources/images/arrow.png')
    buttonBackward =  pygbutton.PygButton((600, 900, 600,482),   normal='resources/images/arrowBackward.png')
    buttonZebra    =  pygbutton.PygButton((100, 150, 640,480),   normal='resources/images/zebraclip.png')
    buttonZebra1   =  pygbutton.PygButton((850, 200, 600, 120),  'Z   E   B   R   A')
    buttonZebra2   =  pygbutton.PygButton((850, 400, 600, 120),  'Z   A   B   R   A')
    buttonZebra3   =  pygbutton.PygButton((850, 600, 600, 120),  'Z   B   R   E   A')
    buttonZebra11  =  pygbutton.PygButton((855, 205, 110, 110),  'Z')
    buttonZebra12  =  pygbutton.PygButton((975, 205, 110, 110),  'E')
    buttonZebra13  =  pygbutton.PygButton((1095, 205, 110, 110), 'B')
    buttonZebra14  =  pygbutton.PygButton((1215, 205, 110, 110), 'R')
    buttonZebra15  =  pygbutton.PygButton((1335, 205, 110, 110), 'A')  

    buttonZebra1.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)
    buttonZebra11.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)
    buttonZebra12.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)
    buttonZebra13.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)
    buttonZebra14.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)
    buttonZebra15.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)

    buttonZebra2.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)
    buttonZebra3.font = pygame.font.Font(None,110)


    button = [buttonZebra,buttonZebra1,buttonZebra2,buttonZebra3]
    button_zebra = [buttonZebra11,buttonZebra12,buttonZebra13,buttonZebra14,buttonZebra15]

    allButtons = button
    windowBgColor = WHITE     

    #6  Event loop
    #while True: 
    while running: 

    #pygame.display.flip()

        for event in pygame.event.get(): # event handling loop

            if event.type == QUIT or (event.type == KEYDOWN and event.key == K_ESCAPE):
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()            
            if 'click' in button[0].handleEvent(event):                                        
                 zebrasound.play()                                   
            if 'click' in button[1].handleEvent(event):                 
                 sound_please(right) 
                 change_color_bg(button[1], GREEN) 

                 change_color_fg(button_zebra[0], GREEN)
                 change_color_bg(button_zebra[0], BLACK)
                 sound_please(zlet)                     

                 change_color_fg(button_zebra[1], GREEN)
                 change_color_bg(button_zebra[1], BLACK)
                 sound_please(elet)

                 change_color_fg(button_zebra[2], GREEN)
                 change_color_bg(button_zebra[2], BLACK)
                 sound_please(blet) 

                 change_color_fg(button_zebra[3], GREEN)
                 change_color_bg(button_zebra[3], BLACK)
                 sound_please(rlet)                      

                 change_color_fg(button_zebra[4], GREEN)
                 change_color_bg(button_zebra[4], BLACK)
                 sound_please(alet)                               
            if 'click' in button[2].handleEvent(event):      
                 sound_please(wrong) 
                 change_color_bg(button[2], RED)                 
            if 'click' in button[3].handleEvent(event):      
                 sound_please(wrong) 
                 change_color_bg(button[3], RED)                       

        pygame.display.update()      
        screen.fill(windowBgColor)       
        buttonForward.draw(screen)      
        for a in allButtons:
           a.draw(screen)       
        for b in button_zebra:
               b.draw(screen)  
        pygame.display.update()
        FPSCLOCK.tick(FPS)      

def change_color_fg(button,color):
    button.fgcolor = color 
    pygame.display.update()    

def change_color_bg(button,color):    
    button.bgcolor = color               
    pygame.display.update()

def sound_please(sound):
    sound.play()
    while pygame.mixer.get_busy():
       time.sleep(1) 
    pygame.display.update()  

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main() 
   for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit(0)
```

`Button[1]` is the big button and `button_zebra 1,2,3,4` are small buttons inside bigbutton.

I have 4 buttons in a bigbutton, When I click the bigbutton and color of it changes.

Comment: Please show us your code. Add it to the question so we can see what you are trying to do.

Comment: Take a look at this question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22284615/python-pygame-pygbutton-detecting

Comment: How can I add code in this post?

Comment: Click on the edit link (at the bottom of your question) and copy paste the code into the box. Then highlight all of your code and click on the "Code Sample" button

Comment: @Deepend: I put code here. You can see and let me know if you know how to resolve this problem..

Comment: I dont know unfortunately, I requested the code so others could look and formatted the question to make it easier to understand. I hope you find an answer and welcome to SO

Answer (score -1):

Since input handling (the section of code that you posted) is usually just one part of the game loop, and you haven't posted the contents of `change_color_fg`, I can only make an educated guess here.

My guess is that `change_color_fg` does not actually update the display, and only changes the color that a button is *supposed* to draw with.  It's my guess partly because it wouldn't make sense to re-draw the display within a function that's executing multiple times within a single frame.

For starters, don't delay in the middle of your update loop.  If you need to do something when a single sound ends, implement a callback, or check playing sounds for completion once every frame until they finish.

For example, with each sound you play, you could either check its length with [`pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.get_length), and then schedule a function to execute after that amount of time which changes the color of your next button and plays your next sound.  Or, you could get the `pygame.mixer.Channel` object [back from `pygame.mixer.Sound.play`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Sound.play), and then check [`pygame.mixer.Channel.get_busy`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.get_busy) until it returns `False`, which would indicate that your sound has stopped playing, at which point you can play the next one.

Comment: I posted full code. I am updating screen in functions also, but still color of the buttons is only changing in the end after playing all sounds.

Comment: @Pink You are updating the screen, but not drawing the buttons after changing the color.  The only time you draw the buttons is at the end of your main loop, after your input handling and delays.